# What is the sharing mode for a class that inherits the sharing model of its caller in a flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, sharing, invocable-method

What happens if a class that uses the `inherited sharing` sharing model is also a class that is a custom Apex action used in a screen flow?

If the flow's "How to Run the Flow" is set to "System Context Without Sharing-Access All Data", for example. Does the class inherits a "with" or "without" sharing context?